# save result of MySql query in variable using node js

Tags: mysql, node.js, save, exec

I want to know how can I save result of MySql query in variable using node js

I used this to connect to mysql and get query

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();


app.get('/informations', function (req, res) {

    var connection = mysql.createConnection(
        {
            host     : 'localhost',
            user     : 'root',
            password : '',
            database : 'dbUsers',
        }
    );

    connection.connect();

    var queryString = 'SELECT * FROM hpform';

    connection.query(queryString, function(err, rows, fields) {
        res.json(rows);


        for (var i in rows) {
            console.log('NomBase: ', rows[i].NomBase);
            console.log('CheminHP: ', rows[i].CheminHP);
            console.log('Chemin: ', rows[i].Chemin);
            console.log('HPuser: ', rows[i].HPuser);
            console.log('pass: ', rows[i].pass);
            console.log('path_pub: ', rows[i].path_pub);
        }
    });
    connection.end();
});
module.exports = app;
```

and I have this in result:

```
[{"HPId":16,"NomBase":"Base","CheminHP":"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Hewlett-Packard\\HP Exstream\\HP Exstream 9.5.102","Chemin":"P:\\\\EXSTREAM\\\\BASES\\\\MACSF_DB_EditiqueV9.5.accdb","HPuser":"admin","pass":"admin","path_pub":"D:\\Users\\hbenkhal\\Desktop\\essaipub"},{"HPId":21,"NomBase":"LMG","CheminHP":"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Hewlett-Packard\\HP Exstream\\HP Exstream 9.5.102","Chemin":"D:\\\\hp_LMG\\\\BaseAccess20160330.accdb","HPuser":"admin","pass":"admin","path_pub":"D:\\Users\\hbenkhal\\Desktop\\essaipub"},{"HPId":22,"NomBase":"Meriem","CheminHP":"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Hewlett-Packard\\HP Exstream\\HP Exstream 9.5.102","Chemin":"D:\\base_meriem\\Test.accdb","HPuser":"admin","pass":"admin","path_pub":"D:\\Users\\hbenkhal\\Desktop\\essaipub"},{"HPId":24,"NomBase":"bouygues","CheminHP":"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Hewlett-Packard\\HP Exstream\\HP Exstream 9.5.102","Chemin":"D:\\\\hp_LMG\\\\bouygues\\\\20160425 - PRODUCTION MEP FE_22606 - Ano314002 Libellé remboursement EDP Appro","HPuser":"admin","pass":"admin","path_pub":"D:\\Users\\hbenkhal\\Desktop\\essaipub"},{"HPId":26,"NomBase":"hamza","CheminHP":"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Hewlett-Packard\\HP Exstream\\HP Exstream 9.5.102","Chemin":"P:\\\\EXSTREAM\\\\BASES\\\\MACSF_DB_EditiqueV9.5.accdb","HPuser":"admin","pass":"admin","path_pub":"D:\\Users\\hbenkhal\\Desktop\\essaipub"}]
```

now I want to save my results as a request to use them in exec command something like this

```
child = exec("\"" + req.session.CheminHP + "/Packager.exe\" -APPLICATION=" + req.params.app + " -ACCESSDB=" + req.session.Chemin + " -EXSTREAMUSER=" + req.session.HPuser + " -EXSTREAMPASSWORD=" + req.session.pass + "  -PACKAGEFILE=" + req.session.path_pub + "\\" + req.params.app + ".pub", function (error, stdout, stderr)
```

Can I have a suggestion to do this.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you get only one row from your query try this:

```
connection.query(queryString, function(err, rows, fields) {
    res.json(rows);

    var elem = rows[0];
    for (var prop in elem) {
      req.session[prop] = elem[prop]; 
    }
});
connection.end();
```

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I've fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much Nikita Namestnikov.
I used what you tell me to do and I add

```
console.log('NomBase: ' + req.session.NomBase);
        console.log('CheminHP: ' + req.session.CheminHPBase);
        console.log('Chemin: ' + req.session.CheminBase);
        console.log('HPuser: ' + req.session.HPuserBase);
        console.log('pass: ' + req.session.passBase);
        console.log('path_pub: ' + req.session.path_pubBase);
```

to see if that work but there is a problem

[image]

When I Use req.session.NomBase, req.session.CheminHPBase,...  in my routes it undefined